# Cursor option required

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using Go and MongoDB for my Project.I used

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{}},{$lookup:{}},{$addFields:{}}])
```

it is working fine in MongoDB, but when I use pipeline in Go, it gives below error

```
The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
```

Go code is

```
matchStage:=bson.M{"$match":bson.M{}}
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{matchStage})
    err = pipeline.All(&resp)
```

Comment: Okay, so what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you are supposed to implement Mongo-Aggregation query in Go.

It should be of the format

```golang
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(
        ctx,
        mongo.Pipeline{<PIPELINE-STAGES>},
        options.Aggregate().SetAllowDiskUse(true),
        )
```

Hence your code should be:

```golang
ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)

matchStage := bson.D{
        {"$match", bson.D{}},
    }
lookupStage := bson.D{
        {"from", ""},
        {"let": bson.D{{}}},
        {"pipeline": bson.A{}},
        {"as": ""},
    }
addFieldsStage := bson.D{
        {"$addFields", bson.D{}},
    }

cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(
    ctx,
    mongo.Pipeline{matchStage, lookupStage, addFieldsStage},
    options.Aggregate().SetAllowDiskUse(true),  // Mongo-Aggregate options if any
    )
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for cursor.Next(ctx) {
    var cursorResult bson.M
    err := cursor.Decode(&cursorResult)  // I world recommend to decode it using a struct instead
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Decoded Cursor: %v", cursorResult)
}

err = cursor.Close(ctx)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

Note: I haven't tested the code in my local. So let me know in case of errors.

Comment: in my code when i used collection.Aggregate() it gives error Aggregate() not defined

Comment: which version of do-mongo driver are you using? Also, make sure that they are imported  ` import ("go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
 "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options")`

Comment: i am using labix.org/v2/mgo library

Comment: i imported both libraries but still gives same error Aggregate() not defined

Comment: The code I provided is for the official go-mongo package. If you try to import both the packages, it will throw an error. There should be only one package, either go-mongo or mgo. I don't know the Aggregation syntax for mgo package, I am afraid I can't help you with mgo package option.

Comment: using v1.3.5 mongo driver

Comment: Then you shouldn't be getting this error. I am using go-mongo v1.3.4 and I have no issues, please check your import statement again also, re-post your entire go code if possible (erasing sensitive information), along with the error you are geiing with its line number

Comment: thanku you for helping me. i have re-post the question